# Abstract Algebra polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, terminology, irreducible-polynomials

More often I came across "irreducible" & "not-irreducible" in polynomial ring. I do understand the terminology "reducible" and "irreducible". But confusing "irreducible" and "not-irredcible". Please provide the differences.

Comment: Not-irreducible is the same as reducible

Comment: So not-irreducible implies reducible. Thanks @Alex Mathers